# Namespace Media does not exist

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing in Unity 4.7.1f1 using Visual Studio 2015 C# on Windows 8. I'm trying to do some bitmap processing using the [Kinect background removal tool](https://github.com/Vangos/kinect-2-background-removal). The class starts with the following lines:

`using System.Windows.Media;`

`using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;`

This produce the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I need this for types `PixelFormat`, `WritableBitmap`, and`Int32Rect`.

My reading, including searches through Unity Answers and Stack Overflow, has indicated the following:

- Adding the assembly in Visual Studio will not have it compile properly. Unity needs to have it added in Unity/Mono.
- This component of Windows is in PresentationCore.dll which you can copy to the project.

I tried the following solutions:

- I copied the PresentationCore.dll file from `Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NetFramework\v4.0\Profile` to the `Assets` folder by dragging it to the 'Project' pane's Assets folder.
- I copied the PresentationCore.dll file from a subfolder of `\Windows\WinSxS` to the `Assets` folder by dragging it to the 'Project' pane's Assets folder.
- I checked I was building for .NET 2.0 and not a subset.

None of this cleared the error. I would restart Unity and load the files in Visual Studios when making a change. How to I get Mono to use accept reference to it? Am I missing something very simple? Like a step after I copy the DLL to the assets folder?

Comment: PresentationCore requires .net3.5 or higher iirc. There are similar build in functionalities in unity itself though. You might want to look into the native functions instead.

Comment: AFAIK Unity uses .NET 3.5 and does not support higher versions. It simply can't compile the dll you copied

Comment: BTW, you must copy dll files to Assets/Plugins

Comment: Thank you both. I've now tried copying from the 3.5 folder and putting it into the Plugins. The error still gets reported.